# Error of the variance

Tags: variance, error

I have a collection of $(x,y,z)$ data points.  I want to compute the mean, $\mu$, and variance, $\sigma^2$, along each axis, as well as the errors on each.  I know that the standard error of the mean is $\Delta \mu = \sigma / \sqrt{N}$, but I'm not familiar with any methods to estimate the error of the variance, $\Delta (\sigma^2)$.  Is there a method to estimate the error of the variance?

In case it makes a difference: I expect the data to be a 3D Gaussian, but I expect the variance to be different along different axes (i.e. $\sigma_x^2 \ne \sigma_y^2 \ne \sigma_z^2$).

The reason I'm looking for this is that the coordinates are the positions of particles that are expected to obey an advection-diffusion law, the means are related to the advection velocity, and the variances are related to the diffusion coefficients.

Comment: what is the underlying equation describing your phenomenon?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to find out.  I believe I will have an advection-diffusion equation: df/dt = d/dx(v f) + d/dx(D df/dx).  However, I generate my coordinates using something like a simplified Monte Carlo method subject to Lorentz forces.  The theory is that this will yield an advection-diffusion equation under certain conditions.

That being said: Analyzing the distribution to see if my data matches the expected behavior is a broader question.  What I'm hoping to learn here is how to estimate the error of the variance (assuming a 3D Gaussian distribution if necessary).

Comment: There are some related threads on the site. I don't know if any of these will answer your question, but you may want to take a look: [Variance of sample Variance](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/79808/7290); [SD of SD](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/631/7290); [Why is chi square used to a CI for the variance?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/76444/7290); [Calculating required N, precision of variance estimate](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/7004/7290); & [What is the distribution of the variance of a sample from an unknown distribution?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/29902/7290)